# Mysql - delete multi table

Tags: mysql

```
DELETE a,b 
FROM a AS a
INNER JOIN b AS b ON a.b_id = b.id
WHERE a.id IN (1,2,3,4)
```

The above query only delete 1 records, why ? i want delete all 4 records

Answer (score 1):

I created a test sample as follows:

use test
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS a;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS b;
CREATE TABLE a (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE b (id  INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO a VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10);
INSERT INTO b VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10);
SELECT * FROM a;
SELECT * FROM b;
DELETE a.* FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.id WHERE a.id IN (1,2,3,4);
SELECT * FROM a;

Here are my results:

lwdba@localhost (DB test) :: use test
Database changed
lwdba@localhost (DB test) :: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS a;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

lwdba@localhost (DB test) :: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS b;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

lwdba@localhost (DB test) :: CREATE TABLE a (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.23 sec)

lwdba@localhost (DB test) :: CREATE TABLE b (id  INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.17 sec)

lwdba@localhost (DB test) :: INSERT INTO a VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10);
Query OK, 10 rows affected (0.06 sec)
Records: 10  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

lwdba@localhost (DB test) :: INSERT INTO b VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10);
Query OK, 10 rows affected (0.06 sec)
Records: 10  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

lwdba@localhost (DB test) :: SELECT * FROM a;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  4 |
|  5 |
|  6 |
|  7 |
|  8 |
|  9 |
| 10 |
+----+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

lwdba@localhost (DB test) :: SELECT * FROM b;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  4 |
|  5 |
|  6 |
|  7 |
|  8 |
|  9 |
| 10 |
+----+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

lwdba@localhost (DB test) :: DELETE a,b FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.id WHERE a.id IN(1,2,3,4);
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.08 sec)

lwdba@localhost (DB test) :: SELECT * FROM a;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  5 |
|  6 |
|  7 |
|  8 |
|  9 |
| 10 |
+----+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

lwdba@localhost (DB test) :: SELECT * FROM b;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  5 |
|  6 |
|  7 |
|  8 |
|  9 |
| 10 |
+----+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Give it a Try !!!

BTW I removed "AS a" and "AS b" from your query and I changed a.b_id to a.id

Comment: hehe thanks , i have a mistake in my query (but in my question it correct :D ). IN ('1,2,3,4') instead IN(1,2,3,4). You only delete in a table ? DELETE a.*

Comment: I tried my sample with DELETE a instead of DELETE a.*. It worked as well !!! In fact, I put back DELETE a,b and ran it. It indeed deleted from table a and table b. I updated my answer to reflect this. Thank you, I now trust DELETE to delete from two tables at the same time !!!

Answer (score -1):

DELETE command doesn't work with JOIN

Comment: i run it and don't get any error notice , but it only delete first record in both tables? what is right way ?

Comment: try this:  DELETE a.*, b.*    
or:   DELETE *