# Can I do a sort of DELETE with JOIN?

Tags: mysql, cascading-deletes

I have this kind of table in my `MySql Database` :

```
CREATE TABLE `forum_categories` (
    `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `description` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
ROW_FORMAT=DEFAULT

CREATE TABLE `forum_topics` (
    `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `category_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `author` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `visits` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `sticky` TINYINT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
ROW_FORMAT=DEFAULT
```

And I'd like, for example, to remove the category (from the table `forum_categories`) with `id=4`. 
But, when I do this, I'd like to remove all rows on the table `forum_topics` with `category_id=4`.

Is it possible to do a sort of `DELETE+JOIN`? 
Unfortunatly (as you can see) my host provider doesnt support `InnoDB` (what a shame..), so I can't use `FOREIGN KEYS` :(

**SOLUTION**

Solved with :

```
DELETE forum_categories.*, forum_topics.* , forum_visits.*, forum_messages.*
FROM forum_categories 
JOIN forum_topics ON forum_categories.id=forum_topics.category_id 
JOIN forum_visits ON forum_topics.id=forum_visits.topic
JOIN forum_messages ON forum_topics.id=forum_messages.topic_id
WHERE forum_categories.id=4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the multi-table syntax also:

`delete a.*, b.* from forum_categories a inner join forum_topics b on a.id = b.category_id where a.id = 4`

Comment: or better yet: `delete a.*, b.* from forum_categories a inner join forum_topics b on a.id = b.category_id where a.id = 4`

Answer (score 3):

Setup a `TRIGGER` to provide the "cascading" effect.

This [MySQL cascading example](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-enforcing-foreign-keys.html) should provide what you are looking for. It specifically calls out how to do it with MyISAM-based tables.

Answer (score 1):

looks like you might be stuck with

```
DELETE FROM fourm_topics WHERE category_id = 4
DELETE FROM forum_categories WHERE id = 4
```

in the same call.

Comment: Yeah, in fact is not my target. After, I'd like to delete all messages from forum_topics with same forum_topics.id=forum_messages.topic_id : a sort of cascading delete :)

Answer (score 1):

I addressed this question a while back

[Mysql - delete multi table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435308/mysql-delete-multi-table/5435796#5435796)